# How to force static library to include it dependencies?

Tags: gcc, compilation, static-libraries, unix-ar

I build my own static library with gcc and ar like this.

```
g++ \
    ... list of library sources ... \
    ... a lot of -L -l -I -D options etc... \
    -c \
    && ar crf ./lib/libpackager.a *.o
```

Then I use this library in my app. Currently I built it like this.

```
g++ \
    myApp.cpp \
    ... same -L -l -I options as in library ... \
    -L. -lpackager \
    -o myApp
```

It works, but I am little odd for me that I need to duplicate all `-l` and `-L` during building the app. Is it possible include all this library dependencies inside the library. My goal to build app like this.

```
g++ myApp.cpp -L. -lpackager -o myApp
```

Comment: Specifying the `-l` and `-L` operations when compiling is irrelevant.  Some versions of GCC warn about arguments that won't be used because they are link-time arguments, and linking won't be used when you include the `-c` flag.  The `ar` command doesn't know what to do with the C compiler's `-l` and `-L` arguments (it might have its own uses for the flags; one version of `ar` accepts but ignores `-l`).  So, you have to specify the dependencies when you link with the static library.  That is the way life has been since the early 70s — that aspect hasn't changed yet.

Comment: Shared libraries can be built with the dependency information.  But not static libraries.

Comment: As I understand I need to build shared library and link it in static way, right?

Comment: No. You either need to build and link a shared library as a shared library, or you need to accept that using a static library means you will need to specify other libraries on the command line when you use this library. There are systems to help manage such information; [`pkg-config`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) is one such.  AFAIK, you cannot link a shared library in a 'static way'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comments into an answer.*</sup>

Specifying the `-l` and `-L` operations when compiling to object files is irrelevant. Some versions of GCC warn about arguments that won't be used because they are link-time arguments, and linking won't be used when you include the `-c` flag.

The `ar` command doesn't know what to do with the C compiler's `-l` and `-L` arguments (it might have its own uses for the flags; one version of `ar` accepts but ignores `-l`).

So, you have to specify the dependencies when you link with the static library. That is the way life has been since the early 70s — that aspect hasn't changed yet.
Shared libraries can be built with the dependency information, but not static libraries.

> As I understand it, I need to build a shared library and link it in a static way, right?

No. You either need to build and link a shared library as a shared library, or you need to accept that using a static library means you will need to specify other libraries on the command line when you use this library. There are systems to help manage such information; [`pkg-config`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) is one such. AFAIK, you cannot link a shared library in a 'static way'.